# Spring Security and WSO2 Authorization

Tags: authentication, spring-security, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to wso2 and its very confusing. I'm developing a web application using authorization Provider: WSO2 Identity Server (IS)

I am looking for minimum configuration on the wso2 side so the simple way is to use SOAP call AuthenticationAdmin services https://host:port/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl

I couldn't find much about the interaction between the authorization server and the resource server and how should it look like.

How to configure spring-security, maybe there is some sample I can look at

Comment: Wso2 provides a selection of authentication protocols that you could use. The most straight-forward is probably OpenID Connect. Here is a tutorial for setting up Spring Security to use OpenID Connect: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more information about the concepts of the OAuth [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/oauth-concepts/). You find how to work with OAuth in WSO2 IS also. You can also refer to the [white paper](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/securing-your-web-service-with-oauth2-using-wso2-identity-server-1/)

[Here](https://medium.com/@balaajanthan/oauth2-login-for-spring-boot-application-with-wso2-identity-server-da0a88893987) is a blog about how to secure Spring Boot based web application using OpenID Connect. This blog includes a sample